# Rust Indexed Access Types (e.g. type Asdf = MyStruct::field)

Tags: rust

Is there a way to define a type in terms of the type of a field of a struct in Rust?

Such as:

```rust
struct Person {
   id: i32,
}

type PersonId = Person::id;
```

(I know that I could define `PersonId` as `i32` and make `Person` use that, but I am not interested in this use case. My particular use case is code-generation, so it would help if my Rust outputs are more similar to the other input language.)

TypeScript has an analogous concept, if this helps explain what I am asking for: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be through the use of [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html).

One gotcha is that you need a trait to define an associated type. In your case, such a trait could be an `Identifiable`:

```
trait Identifiable {
    type Id;

    fn id(&self) -> Self::Id;
}
```

Your structure would implement said trait:

```
struct Person {
   id: i32,
}

impl Identifiable for Person {
    type Id = i32;

    fn id(&self) -> Self::Id {
        self.id
    }
}

type PersonId = <Person as Identifiable>::Id;
```

It could be used like this:

```
let id: PersonId = 23;
let person = Person { id };
```

As per the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0223), the reason that we cannot simply use `Person::Id` is that Person might implement two different traits with identically-named associated types. This syntax allows disambiguation between the two.

Interestingly, as the associated type is defined in a trait, it's entirely possible to define the struct's field type as the alias that's specified below it.

It is therefore legal to write:

```
struct Person {
   id: PersonId, // ---> instead of i32
}
```

See it in action in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f7f2282f43685dcf8ceba0cf9363cfc).